# How to deploy vtiger with capistrano?

Tags: capistrano3, vtiger

I'm trying do setup vtiger as a CRM and trying to deploy changes with capristranorb. Every time I do a deploy I get this error:

> **Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file.**

Anyone has an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include what steps you are taking, so that community can figure out which step is going wrong.

Comment: Corrected some spelling

Comment: @jonathan - If you still facing issue please add your config.inc.php file content so i can provide you solution.